# Move li items on click between lists

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to do the following:

I have three lists, list `A`, list `B`, list `C`.

I want to move items ON CLICK out of list `A` into list `B` and items out of list `C` into list `B`, so `A` and `C` are left and right, and `B` is the "container list" for items from list `A` and `C`.

List `B`, the container list, should be empty at the beginning.

**Edit: This should work both ways if possible, so if I click an item that I put into list `B` that should be sorted back into list `A` and `C`.**

Here is a very simple example of how it looks like right now: https://jsfiddle.net/3ds06kf0/2/

```css
#listA,
#listB,
#listC {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 2.5em;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="listA" class="connectedSortable">List A
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>

<ul id="listB" class="connectedSortable">List B
  <!-- THIS IS EMPTY AT THE BEGINNING -->
</ul>

<ul id="listC" class="connectedSortable">List C
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

I have found some complex solutions including Dragula JS and the such, but I believe that there are simpler solutions to this using basic jquery, I just can't get my head around it :(

Comment: Should the elements in B be able to be moved back to the list they came from?  Are you expecting any sort of sorting?

Comment: @Taplar Yes and yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move items with `appendTo`

Try this code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$("#listA").on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).appendTo('#listB');
});

$("#listC").on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).appendTo('#listB');
});
```

Comment: That looks great! I tried out the appendTo function but I think I didn't use the # to define the id ...

How hard would it be to enable appending the items back to their initial list? And how hard would it be to do all this in the initial sorted order? :)

Comment: Thank you SO much @AllenBooTung! Does this have the option to remember the sorting when clicking items back into their initial lists?

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery to your code.. it will definitely solve you problem

```
$('#listA li').click(function(){
var elem=$(this).text();
$("#listB").append("<li class='ui-state-highlight'>" +elem+ "</li>");

});

$('#listC li').click(function(){
var ele=$(this).text();
$("#listB").append("<li class='ui-state-highlight'>" +ele+ "</li>");

});
```

I am not i can show you or not.. But here is the jsfiddle link
https://jsfiddle.net/3ds06kf0/66/

Comment: yes you can use $(this).clone(); for the same result